# meaning of the phrasal verb "lock down" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is in [Crash Course A&P](https://youtu.be/DlqyyyvTI3k). It is at 7 minute and 52 second. Here it goes:

> An area of your brainstem, called the pons, contains two different centers that **lock down** your urination control, or lack of it.

I have looked up all the meanings *lock down* has, but still not sure what the speaker means there. Does he mean the two centers have control over urination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the speaker intends a meaning such as **determine**.

The only dictionary definition of **lock down** I can find with a similar kind of meaning is

> to make an arrangement definite so that it will not change

as in

> we need to lock down a date for this meeting

I would not recommend the use of lock down as shown in your example. There is almost certainly an English word that means exactly what needs to be said. Perhaps **determine** or **implement** or **provide**. The phrase **lock down** has strong other meanings, relating to police actions and computer security; I can't see a good reason to use it in this context.